# What is the Instance/object in the code?

Tags: objective-c, object, xcode4

Could Somebody please describe to me what the instance/object is in the following Code (objective-C). I'm confused because the (-) void before void means that its a method for an instance, but I don't know where the instance/object is.

```
  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
//interface section
@interface Fraction: NSObject
- (void) print;
- (void)setNumerator: (int) n;
- (void)setDenominator: (int) d;
@end
//implementation section
@implementation Fraction
{
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
}
-(void) print;
{
    NSLog(@"%i/%i",numerator,denominator);
}
-(void) setNumerator:(int)n
{
    numerator = n;
}
-(void)setDenominator:(int)d
{
    denominator = d;
}
@end
//program section
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
//this is a program to work with fractions-class version
    @autoreleasepool {
        Fraction *myFraction;
        //create an instance of a fraction
        myFraction = [Fraction alloc];
        myFraction = [myFraction init];
        //set fraction to 1/3
        [myFraction setNumerator:1];
        [myFraction setDenominator:3];
        //display the fraction via print methoD


        NSLog(@"the value of myFraction is:");
        [myFraction print];
         }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

myFraction is the instance of the Fraction class. Instance methods have to be addressed to an instance rather than a class, and as you can see, print, setNumerator, and setDenominator are all addressed to myFraction.

Comment: What are the instance methods?

Comment: @user1706978, any method in a class that has a "-" in front of it -- in this case print, setNumerator, setDenominator, and init.